# Android Image Orientation issue

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I have a method to **get photo orientation** but when image is taken on portrait mode and after selected from gallery this method rotate to flip vertical.

**UPDATE**

This method is now used to show images selected from gallery

```
public static Boolean ShowImagesCapture(Context context, Uri PATH_IMAGE, ImageView view,int width, int height){

    int orientation=0;
    Boolean success = true;
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap =null;
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            String selectedImagePath = getPath(PATH_IMAGE,context);
            bitmap = decodefilebitmap(selectedImagePath,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight());
            orientation=GetPhotoOrientation(context,getRealPathFromURI(context,PATH_IMAGE));
        }

        else {
            ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor;

            try {
                parcelFileDescriptor = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(PATH_IMAGE, "r");
                FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
                parcelFileDescriptor.close();
                orientation=GetPhotoOrientation(context,getRealPathFromURI(context,PATH_IMAGE));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        switch (orientation) {


            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                bitmap=rotateBitmap(bitmap,3,width,height);
                view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                break;

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                bitmap=rotateBitmap(bitmap,8,width,height);
                view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                break;

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE:
                break;

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                bitmap=rotateBitmap(bitmap,6,width,height);
                view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                break;

            default:
                view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }

        bitmap = null;

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        success= false;
    }
    System.gc();
    return success;
}
```

Comment: are you sure it gets the right orientation mode when a picture is portrait?

Comment: forever return ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED from gallery

Comment: https://github.com/recurser/exif-orientation-examples   try these images and maybe nolonger you get 'undefined'. Not every camera will include meta-data in the img file ( exif header)

Comment: reformatting and title clarification